# problema/duda con condiciones if o switch

Tags: php, mysql

Aquí de nuevo preguntando y solicitando de su amable ayuda, tengo un detalle a la hora mandar imprimir unos resultados con las condiciones `if`, aunque no se si sea la mejor manera de hacerlo o con `Switch case` ya que igual lo he hecho pero no me arroja lo esperado.

En mi BD Laboratorio tengo una tabla de `resul_grupo_rh`, la cual tengo las columnas de `id_resul`, `id_ medico`, `id_cliente`, `num_factura`, `fecha`, `grup_san`, `fac_rh`, `vih`, `vdrl`.

Como hago para comparar e imprimir los valores o si lo estoy haciendo bien o hay alguna otra manera de verificar cada una de las condiciones para imprimir los 4 a la vez, 3 de ellos si uno esta vacío, 2 de ellos si los otros 2 están vacíos o no imprimir nada y regresar o mandar un mensaje de que no hay valores que imprimir.

```
//incluyo las librerias de conexion a la bd
include ("config/db.php");
include ("config/conexion.php");

$num_fac = $_GET["num_factura"];
$id_cliente = $_GET["idcliente"];
$fecha = $_GET["fecha"];
$id_medico = $_GET["idmedico"];

$sql = "SELECT c.nombre_cliente,q.* from clientes c,resul_grupo_rh q where q.numero_factura='" . $num_fac . "' 
     and q.id_cliente='" . $id_cliente . "' and c.id_cliente=q.id_cliente and q.fecha='" . $fecha . "'";
$resul = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$rw_resul = mysqli_fetch_array($resul);

$consulta = "select * from medicos where id_medico='" . $id_medico . "'";
$query_consulta = mysqli_query($con, $consulta);
$resultado_medico = mysqli_fetch_array($query_consulta);

//si en la consulta de BD mis valores o campos de vih y vdrl estan vacios imprimo Grupo Sanguineo y factor RH
if (empty($rw_resul["vih"]) and empty($rw_resul["vdrl"]))
{
    //imprimo en PDF solo resultados de Grupo Sanguineo y factor RH
    echo "$rw_resul["grup_san"]";
    echo "$rw_resul["fac_rh"]";
}

//si en la consulta de BD mi valor de vdrl esta vacio imprimo Grupo Sanguineo y factor RH y VIH
if (isset($rw_resul["vih"]) and isset($rw_resul["vih"]) and isset($rw_resul["vih"]) and empty($rw_resul["vdrl"]))
{
    //imprimo en PDF solo resultados de Grupo Sanguineo y factor RH
    echo "$rw_resul["grup_san"]";
    echo "$rw_resul["fac_rh"]";
    echo "$rw_resul["vih"]";
}

//si en la consulta de BD mi valor de vih esta vacio imprimo Grupo Sanguineo y factor RH y VDRL
if (isset($rw_resul["vih"]) and isset($rw_resul["vih"]) and empty($rw_resul["vih"]) and isset($rw_resul["vdrl"]))
{
    //imprimo en PDF solo resultados de Grupo Sanguineo y factor RH
    echo "$rw_resul["grup_san"]";
    echo "$rw_resul["fac_rh"]";
    echo "$rw_resul["vdrl"]";
}
```

Mi pregunta es como le hago para imprimir que cuando los 4 valores en mi BD están vacíos no imprima nada y me regrese a mi pagina diciéndome que no hay ningún dato para imprimir.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Este codigo no hace lo que esperas?

Answer (score 1):

Podrías crear un lazo IF que envuelva los tres if:

```
if($rw_resul["grup_san"] || $rw_resul["fac_rh"] || $rw_resul["vih"] || $rw_resul["vdrl"]) {
    // A este lazo se entra si cualquiera de los anteriores NO está vacío
    // Aquí irian los 3 if que ya codificaste
} else {
    // Mensaje indicando que todo está vacío
}
```

Una nota, la forma correcta de hacer esos *echo* es:

```
echo $rw_resul["grup_san"];    // sin comillas adicionales
```

Answer (score 0):

Desde php7 se introdujo **null coalescing operator (??)**. El uso de este operador simplifica el uso de condicionales de manera que su código podría quedar algo como:

```php
 echo "$rw_resul["grup_san"]" ?? "";
 echo "$rw_resul["fac_rh"]" ?? "";
 echo "$rw_resul["vdrl"]" ?? "";
 echo "$rw_resul["vih"]" ?? "";
```

Esto imprimirá la cadena vacía (¨¨) en el caso de no estar seteada la variable correspondiente. Esto le evitará el uso de condicionales y le ahorrará bastantes líneas de código. Puede ver en el siguiente enlace https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php7/php7_coalescing_operator.htm

Por otra parte,  trabajando desde el enfoque de sus condicionales, notara que la impresion de sus variables *$rw_resul["grup_san"]* y *$rw_resul["fac_rh"]* son comunes, por lo que puede tener dos opciones: Puede imprimirla siempre o condicionarlas a ellas dos. Con respecto a *vdrl* y *vih* si podrá hacer comparaciones por separadas:

```php
//opcion 1

 echo "$rw_resul["grup_san"]";
 echo "$rw_resul["fac_rh"]";

 if(isset($rw_resul["vdrl"]) {
     echo "$rw_resul["vdrl"]";
 }

 if(isset($rw_resul["vih"]) {
     echo "$rw_resul["vih"]";
 }
```

```php
//Opción dos igual a la anterior pero con condicionales en las primeras líneas

//Puede verificar con && o || segun sea su caso
if(isset($rw_resul["fac_rh"]) && isset($rw_resul["grup_san"]) {
   echo "$rw_resul["grup_san"]";
   echo "$rw_resul["fac_rh"]";
 }

 if(isset($rw_resul["vdrl"]) {
     echo "$rw_resul["vdrl"]";
 }

 if(isset($rw_resul["vih"]) {
     echo "$rw_resul["vih"]";
 }
```

Queda de usted cual enfoque se adapta mejor a su código, saludos!